# How to retrieve data from DataSet to ListBox?

Tags: c#, sql

All I am getting is the empty listBox while retrieving data from DataSet. Heres the code:

```
DataSet dt_product = dBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT");

listBx_prod.DataSource=dt_product.Tables[0].Columns[1].ExtendedProperties.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

I debugged and my DataSet successfully retrieves data from Database. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Till I know you can not cast i.e ToList() for a single column..

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns `int`, not a `DataSet`.

Comment: @ Bhavik: I want to show only one column in my listbox from dataset.. Is there any other work around to achieve this?

Comment: @ Dennis: ExecuteNonQuery() is a dummy function in my class that returns dataset .. Sorry for that confusion . I will edit the name afterwards

Comment: you shouldn't change your title to 'solved' when it's answered correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit that i don't know why you are trying to read the `PropertyCollection` from the second `DataColumn` in your first table of the `DataSet` via [`ExtendedProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at all.

But since you've mentioned that you just want to show the data in the `ListBox`:

```
listBx_prod.DataSource = dt_product.Tables[0];
listBx_prod.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
listBx_prod.ValueMember = "ProductId";
```

Comment: Actually i am all new to this. Can you tell me the exact difference between DisplayMember and ValueMember. Because in my case both achieves the same result.Whether I use listBx_prod.DisplayMember = "ProductName"; or listBx_prod.ValueMember = "ProductName";

Comment: @Sadiq: `DisplayMember` is the property that should be diplayed and `ValueMember` is the property that should be used to identify an item. Normally you would chose the primary key if it's a database object.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `DataSource` to `DataTable` and set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`:

```
listBox1.DataSource = dt_product.Tables[0];
listBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```